# Помогите сверстать фигуру

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размеры все на фото в px. Желательно чтобы это был div, помогите пожалуйста, плохо понимаю, как это делать.

Comment: Слишком абстрактная задача. Навскидку - css `clip-path`.

Comment: Кроме `clip-path`, можно использовать псевдоэлемент, `::before` или `::after` чтобы добавить часть детали справа

Comment: У Вас задача сродни тетрису - там надо начинать с алгоритмов и логики, а не с визуального оформления. В вашем случае, проще картинкой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
div {
  font-size: 54px;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-left: 1em solid green;
  padding: 1em 0 2em;
  background: green;
  background-clip: content-box;
  filter: drop-shadow(.125em .125em .0625em #030);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```